# TextView vs Canvas Paint - SIZE (Android)

Tags: android, canvas, textview

So I'm setting my text view size and my canvas paint size to the SAME number of pixels. The problem is the text view is bigger than the canvas paint text. My Code:

```
editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
paint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
```

Actually depending on the canvas dimensions, the paint text gets smaller or bigger. I want them to be exactly the same

Comment: I figured out the following: The layout height and width (where the edittext is) is always the same. The canvas changes depending on the image I'm choosing. Is there anyway I could use the layout height and width to set the canvas paint textsize?

Comment: One more thing: layout height: 2068 & layout width: 1440. When the canvas height is bigger than the width the font sizes is the same. When the width is bigger than the height, the canvas text gets smaller.

Comment: FOR SOME REASON: paint.setTextSize is not working for images which the width is bigger than the height.

Comment: Same issue, did you found any solution?